# groovy :pass class(domain) as parameter and call static method dynmically

Tags: grails, inheritance, reflection, groovy

i have a tree of inheritance of Class

```
class Perfer{

   String param
    String value
}

class PerferChp extends Prefer{
    static belongsTo=[chp:Chp]
}


class PerferSec extends Prefer{
 static belongsTo=[sec:Sec]

}
```

When i try to pass domain class as parameter , i try this:

```
   Prefer find(GormStaticApi<Prefer> preferenceFamily,String param){
            preferenceFamily.findByParam(param);

   }
```

But in vain

Comment: What is `findParam`? Are you trying to search on class `instance` ?

Comment: non ;no ; findByParam (static method Generated by Gorm )==>updated

Comment: Try the use findBy on actual class `Prefer` not the instance.

Comment: As Alidad say, findBy is a static method, so you cannot use it in the instance.